# How to show $(A \cap B^c \cap C^c) \cup (A \cap B \cap C^c) \cup (A \cap B^c \cap C) = A\backslash(B \cap C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I should show the following equation with the rules for sets:
$(A \cap B^c \cap C^c) \cup (A \cap B \cap C^c) \cup (A \cap B^c \cap C) = A\backslash(B \cap C)$

I drew the diagramms for the sets and so it is logical that the equality must hold. But i don't know how to who that with the rules for the sets.

Anyone here who could help me with that?

Comment: Drawing the diagrams is already an excellent start. Do you know the rules how to 'multiply out' unions, ie $(X \cap Y) \cup Z=(X \cup Z)\cap (Y \cup Z)$?

Comment: I know them with just one set out of the brackets but i have never done that with such a long expression like the left side of my equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that 
$$(A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c})\cup(A\cap B\cap C^{c})\cup(A\cap B^{c}\cap C)$$
$$=((A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c})\cup(A\cap B\cap C^{c}))\cup((A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c})\cup(A\cap B^{c}\cap C))$$
$$=(A\cap C^{c})\cup(A\cap B^{c})=(A\setminus C)\cup(A\setminus B)=A\setminus(B\cap C)$$
where in the second equation we use the fact that
$(U\cap V)\cup(U\cap V^{c})=U$.